# Different wkhtmltopdf version between local and server, installed for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, ruby-on-rails-2

We have app based Ruby on Rails -v 2.3.18, and have problem on wkhtmltopdf version.
In my local, OSX El Capitan 10.11.3, by installing,

```
gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary -v 0.9.9.1
```

and then,

```
wkhtmltopdf -V
```

I will have wkhtmltopdf version **0.9.9**.

But in our server, Ubuntu 13.10 (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-12-generic x86_64), with the same gem wkhtmltopdf-binary installing, the wkhtmltopdf version is **0.9.6**.

I have tried to install newest gem version on server,

```
gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary -v 0.9.9.3
```

but wkhtmltopdf version still same, **0.9.6**.

I need to use **0.9.9** on server. Anybody can help us? Need sugest.

Thank you.

Note: we have already used same version of ruby (1.8.7) and rails (2.3.18), both on my local and server.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of `which wkhtmltopdf` on your server? My guess is it's something in `/usr/local/bin`, which means 1) you have wkhtmltopdf installed on your server, and 2) that installed version is taking precedence over your installed gem version, which is why you're not seeing the latest version. You have a few options I can think of:

1. Make sure you've installed binstubs for wkhtmltopdf, then whenever you use wkhtmltopdf in your Ruby code, instead of calling `wkhtmltopdf`, call `bin/wkhtmltopdf`. This should force your code to use the latest, gem-installed version.
2. Remove the local wkhtmltopdf version from your system (`sudo apt-get remove wkhtmltopdf`, perhaps?)  With it gone, your server should default to the gem-installed version.
3. Upgrade your system wkhtmltopdf version to the right version. This might require installing it from source, since your Ubuntu version is fairly old.

As a note, this sort of problem is easier to avoid if you don't provision and maintain your servers by hand. Container technology, like Docker or the Cedar stack used by Heroku, or just provisioning tech like Vagrant or Otto, allows you to build a barebones server from the ground-up each time. That means you can update server dependencies easily and don't need to rely on gems like wkhtmltopdf-binary.